# Generate Quote - Merge Documents

Tags: pdf, quote

We're trying to streamline our quote to cash system a bit and are migrating to Salesforce quotes.

One of the things our sales team is asking for is that we have the ability to do the following:

1. User clicks a button and a word document is generated with our MSA
   language as well as the information contained in the quote. This document would be redlined by the customer
2. User can upload redlined version of the document and SFDC will generate the word document which is then sent for signature.

Are either/both of these things possible in salesforce? Are there any appexchange packages folks have used to do something similar?

Thanks

Comment: Conga Composer will easily generate Word documents from merge fields. As for merging the redlined changes automatically ... I'm not sure

Answer (score 0):

I have done something like this in the past, but not without some custom code.

We used Docusign (from the AppExchange) and leveraged its API to redline WordDocs based on tags entered within it (think ~~NAME~~).

I am not sure there are any other products out there that will do a more complete job, but it is possible, we had very specific HIPAA requirements that made other solutions unacceptable, so we did not research them much.

Comment: Were reps generating word docs and uploading to Docusign or would docusign in SFDC generate the word docs?

Comment: Both ways. Some forms were state-mandated, those we provided. Sometimes the reps needed to upload specific ad-hoc documents.